# How do I loop over this outerHTML code to get out certain data? (I don't know how to webscrape it so I want to try this)

Tags: python, pandas, screen-scraping, census

I am trying to get a list that matches India's districts to its district codes as they were during the 2011 population census. Below I will post a small subset of the outerHTML I copied from a government website. I am trying to loop over it and extract a string and an int from each little html box and store these ideally in a pandas dataframe on the same row. The HTML blocks look like this, I represent 2, there are around 700 in my txt file:

```
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="5%">1</td>
                                                <td>603</td>
                                                <td align="left">**NICOBARS**</td>
                                                <td align="left">NICOBARS                                          </td>
                                                <td align="left">ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS(State)</td>
                                                <td align="left">NIC</td>
                                                <td align="left">02</td>
                                                <td align="left">**638**</td>
                                                <td align="left">




                                                            Not Covered


                                                </td>
                                                <td width="5%" align="center"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:viewEntityDetailsInPopup('603', 'globalviewDistrictDetail.do', 'globaldistrictId');"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="5%" align="center"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:viewEntityDetailsInPopup('603', 'viewDistrictHistoryReport.do', 'globaldistrictId');"><i class="fa fa-history" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="5%" align="center">

                                                </td>
                                                <td width="3%" align="center">
                                                 <!-- Merging issue revert beck 05/10/2017 -->


                                                    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:viewLandRegionGISMapInPopup(2,'603','L','D');"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="5%">2</td>
                                                <td>632</td>
                                                <td align="left">**NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN**</td>
                                                <td align="left">NORTH AND MIDDLE ANDAMAN                          </td>
                                                <td align="left">ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS(State)</td>
                                                <td align="left">NMA</td>
                                                <td align="left"></td>
                                                <td align="left">**639**</td>
                                                <td align="left">




                                                            Not Covered
```

I have put ** around ** the values that I want to get from the text file. I was wonder how I could loop through this text to extract this data. I thought about start counting  each time after I encounter  and than extract the data of the 1st and 6st  but I don't know how to code this. Hope anyone is willing to help out. Or maybe anyone who already has this list, would be great!

Comment: I highly recommend that you check out the "beautiful soup" package: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ 
and https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: It's fairly easy to do with lxml and xpath. If you can use them, please post the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to get the text of the entire html table, you can use `df = pd.read_html(html_text_string)`.  50% of the time, it works everytime!

[pd.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) <-- docs